# Why don't JavaScript libraries use try-catch blocks more often?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch, libraries

I'm still relatively new to JavaScript, coming from a more classical (i.e. Java, also ActionScript 3.0) background. I'm finding that it's common for an incorrect implementation of a library/framework's API to break things further up the call stack, without clear indication that it's application code (not library code) breaking things.

For example, a jQuery.trigger() call may invoke a handler that throws an error, and that invocation is not wrapped in a try-catch (nor implements any other kind of error protection), and prevents all other handlers from firing.

I understand an error *should* halt execution, but it seems like library code could be better sandboxed from application code, and I see this kind of breakage much more frequently in JS libs than in other languages I've worked with.

Comment: One word: performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, because it's a pain to catch a single exception:

```
try {
    doSomething();
} catch(e) {
    if (e instanceof SomeException) {
        // handle SomeException
    } else {
        throw e; // and lose stacktrace information :-(
    }
}
```

and catching *all* exceptions is usually a wrong thing.

Secondly, because the exception hierarchy of JavaScript itself is very poor in differentiating different kinds of error and providing informational properties about them. JavaScript prefers to do something that you *might* have meant and quietly break when it wasn't, than to raise an error (see `undefined` et al). It is also historically inconsistent between browsers (especially DOM exceptions). This means there is no culture of using exceptions and that inherits into library design.

Comment: @Mike: heh. jQuery is a good example of how exceptions are used in real-world JS: it uses catch-all to pick up browser implementation errors that can't otherwise be sniffed for.

Answer (score 1):

What bobince said but also, even mentioning `try-catch` in your function currently means nothing in that function will be optimized. See [here](http://jsperf.com/213123123901230291), note the JSPerf is not meant to show magnitude, which can be up to 1000x (or whatever) difference between optimized and unoptimized code. You can put more code in the tests and you should see the relative difference grow larger and larger.

See [V8 source](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/hydrogen.cc#L3772) and [SpiderMonkey bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=866888)

This is radically different from e.g. Java where merely mentioning try-catch doesn't really affect anything at all in terms of performance, it is when an exception actually happens that you pay (and then it doesn't matter)